# Brushing up on python, why isn't this throwing a ValueError?

Tags: python

I'm brushing up on my python. I've been coding in java for a year, but I'm about to take an algorithms class in Python. In preparation, I am duplicating the Lights Out puzzle game as a personal practice. I've written the first logic for the light object, and I've designed it to throw an error when I construct a Light() with a negative 0 value, but it won't throw an exception no matter what I construct the object with.

For example:
`light Light(1,1)` is valid, but `light Light(-1,-1)` should throw a ValueError. Where am I going wrong?

```
# Light.py represents a light object for LightsOut game.
# written by nrsmac

class Light:
    # Light.py represents a light object for LightsOut game.
    # written by nrsmac

    #Constants for Light States
    OFF = 0
    ON  = 1

    #Each light has a positive x and y position, negative 1 by defailt
    x = -1
    y = -1

    currentState = OFF

    #Constructor here
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        if self.isValidLocation() == False:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Location!')

    def toggle(self): # TODO: Make this change color
        if self.currentState == self.ON:
            self.currentState = self.OFF
        elif self.currentState == self.OFF:
            self.currentState = self.ON

    def printCurrentLightState(self):
        print(self.currentState)

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def getY(self):
        return self.y

    def setLightState(self, state):
        self.currentState = state

    def isValidLocation(self):
        if self.x < 0 | self.y < 0:
            return False
```

Does python always have this many `self` calls? It's starting to get exhausting from a Java perspective.

Comment: Use `or`, not `|`. Note that it wouldn't be `|` in Java either. On the topic of exhaustion, I think that's largely because you are coding in Python as if it were Java. It's not Java. It's important to learn Python idioms, rather than simply transliterate Java.

Comment: `|` is the bitwise or function, it has higher precedence than the comparisons so your if condition is `self.x < (0 | self.y) < 0` which is the same as `self.x < self.y < 0` which is a valid python conditional for is `self.y` in the range `self.x` to `0` and so for `Light(-1,-1)` `-1` isn't in the range `(-1,0)`.

Comment: Can you clarify the validation of the x and y value? You only want to construct objects with x and y values above 0?

Comment: _Each light has a positive x and y position, negative 1 by default_ Hmm... As an aside, which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I think that in your case the usage of `|` is not correct. You have to use `or`, like so:

```
if (self.x < 0) or (self.y < 0):
```

Answer (score 2):

Basic getters/setters like that aren’t a thing in Python.

Having to type `self` over and over again is indeed annoying. However, we also have IDEs and text editors which support autocompletion, so it shouldn’t be a massive issue.

---

This is what I would do to make the code more pythonic:

```py
@dataclass(init=False)
class Light:
    x: int
    y: int
    is_on: bool

    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, is_on: bool = False) -> None:
        if x < 0 or y < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid location arguments in Light constructor: {x}, {y}')
        else:
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.is_on = is_on

    def toggle(self) -> None:
        self.is_on = not self.is_on
```

It's a work in progress, I think it can still be improved.

Comment: thank you, what is the purpose of declaring a boolean like this? `is_on: bool = False`

Comment: @nrsmac That was me setting a default value for an instance variable the wrong way... Oops.

Comment: @nrsmac Did you ever figure this out?